# Use of Ember evented in a service for publishing/subscribing to events

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using an event-bus service in my app as below;

```
import Evented from '@ember/object/evented';
import Service from '@ember/service';

export default Service.extend(Evented, {
  publish: function(){
    return this.trigger.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  subscribe: function(){
    this.on.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  unsubscribe: function(){
    this.off.apply(this, arguments);
  }
})
```

Now I consume this from my app as below. I have an event-mixin which is kind of like a wrapper as below;

```
export default Mixin.create({
  events: service('event-bus'),
  subscribe: function(eventName, callback){
    this.get('events').on(eventName, this, callback);
  },
  unsubscribe: function(eventName, callback){
    this.get('events').off(eventName, this, callback);
  }    
})
```

Also, to actually use this in a component, I have;

```
import events from '../mixins/event-mixin';
export default Component.extend (events, {

  eventsToListen: function(){
    return [{
      eventName: "enableBtn",
      callBack: $..proxy(this.enableBtn, this);
    }]
  }
}
```

I have showed few parts of the relevant code here.
While I understand the Observer pattern, the actual code has me a bit confused.

Specifically, in my event-mixin, I have code like

```
this.get('events').on(eventName, this, callback);
```

However, if I look at my event-bus which is like a common f/w service which I consume, it has

```
subscribe: function(){
    this.on.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

I am confused as to there is no call made from my app directly to `publish/subscribe/unsubscribe` methods defined in event-bus (instead I have `this.get('events').on(....)`)

How does it work ?

Answer (score 1):

The actual `Ember.evented` pattern uses [on](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.17/classes/Evented/methods/on?anchor=on), [off](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.17/classes/Evented/methods/off?anchor=off), and 
[trigger](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.17/classes/Evented/methods/trigger?anchor=trigger) as the main API. Your event bus service appears to be a wrapper around these functions, conforming `Ember.Evented` to the more generic pub/sub pattern.

The following code

```
publish: function(){
  return this.trigger.apply(this, arguments);
},
subscribe: function(){
  this.on.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

has effectively aliased `trigger` -> `publish` and `on` -> `subscribe`. Why these aliased functions are not used in your codebase is something no one but your teammates can answer (or perhaps a search through version control history). From the code you've shown, the components in your app are using the `event-bus` as the event source, but are using the `Ember.Evented` API directly.

Comment: Hey....thanks a lot....I am still wondering if the code in my event-bus is coming in the picture coz in my event-mixin, I have this.get('events').on(eventName, this, callback);

So am still confused as to when publish/subscribe/unsubscribe methods defined in my event-bus service is of any use?

Comment: Someone on the project exposed the aliased functions as I described above. `publish` `subscribe` provide nothing more than delegation to the `Ember.Evented` functions. if you search your codebase for those strings and find none, then they're not used.